# Set starting Activity with code in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-activity

im new in developing Android Apps.
I know how to set the starting Activity with the AndroidManifest.xml, but i need a way to check something first before i choose the starting Activity.

My Problem:
I created a loginActivity and a mainActivity.
I want to do the following: If i log me in, i'll set a flag to 1 and at the next app start, i want show directly the mainActivity and not the login.

Is there any way to do that? I thought about creating a splashscreen where i can check if im logged in before showing the first Activity.

Thanks, Philip

Updated Code - working:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // get preferences
    SharedPreferences userDetails = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userdetails", 0);
    String savedEmail = userDetails.getString("email", "");
    String savedPassword = userDetails.getString("password", "");
    Boolean savedRemember = userDetails.getBoolean("remember", false);
    Boolean savedLogged = userDetails.getBoolean("logged", false);

    // check if already logged in
    if(savedLogged) {
        // start the overview
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOverview.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else {
        // initialize the form layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // get views
        this.email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        this.password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        this.remember = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRemember);

        // set values to views
        this.email.setText(savedEmail);
        this.password.setText(savedPassword);
        this.remember.setChecked(savedRemember);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar in one of my apps. I let the user chose weather it should auto-login or not. This is saved in the `SharedPreferences`.

When the app starts and in the mainpage, you should check - **BEFORE** the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` and set `finish();` after `startActivity();`

```
if(savedLogged) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOverview.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a splash screen.

When the user successfully logs into your app, set a boolean flag in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to true. Check if this flag is true in the login activity's `onCreate()` and if it is, use an `Intent` to launch the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to display your activity. Not sure what exactly your code flow is going to be but you can safely start i.e. with LoginActivity. in your `onCreate()` check if you are already logged (whatever it means for you) and if so instantly start MainActivity killing LoginActivity with `finish()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, i done that know (see code at my first post). Its working fine, but when i start the app, i see the login screen for a short time before the new screen comes. Is there an event before the Activity Layout gets initializied?

Comment: Do your check before you call `setContentView()`. Also fix your code so `finish();` is called **AFTER** `startActivity();`

Comment: So now i done that (see updated post #1). Its working perfectly, but for a short moment the other activity is also visible, but i dont think that somebody will see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going with a splashscreen would be a good idea. Starting the loginActivity would show the login screen for a split second. This would be undesirable.

Comment: Jeah i tried it now with that, and that was my problem. It doesnt looks good if i start with my login screen..